# get random value from mysql

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I have a table called users which has unique username and have 4 questions regarding to each username which they answered during registration saved in mysql database. what i want to do is make a two step login form where the person types username and password in first and once click submit i fetch one of the questions from database which the user answered and provide it as a second step login. This second question i want is to be taken at random. Plus i want to keep track of number of incorrect attempts. But im stuck on second step, how to get random and check incorrect login attempts. Need a little help. I'm using mysql as backend and working with RoR. My table looks like this

```
Members
{ username
password
question1
question2
question3
question4
answer1
answer2
answer3
answer4 }
```

And all the fields are string!

Comment: You can supply the random column name from RoR part into mysql?? Idea like, add all column name in to array and use to shuffle and get the random column name from RoR coding and pass that value into mysql query.

Comment: i have the username from first part of log in and i want to fetch a random question from database for second part as per username and also verify the answer @user876345

Comment: You can pass username always, along with random question columns?

Comment: Its a simple two step login. The place im stuck is how to get random question from database by the user and later verify it and also keep track of failed attempts made

Comment: select question1 from Members ORDER BY RAND();  `question1` and `question2` .. etc are randomly passed from RoR coding.

Answer (score 0):

the following code generates a random number(100 - 500):

```
FLOOR(RAND() * 401) + 100
```

Generically, `FLOOR(RAND() * (<max> - <min> + 1)) + <min>` generates a number between  and  inclusive.

Comment: but i want a random question to be taken as per my username from the database not just any random number @zaheer

Answer (score 0):

if you need to randomly pick one of the question fields, access the attribute as such:

```
self.send("question#{(1..4).to_a.sample}")
```

where self is your Member instance.

If you need to do the same for 'answer', which is likely since you'll have to validate the user's entry, then this approaches a more complete implementation.

```
my_random = (1..4).to_a.sample
fail_count = 0
question = self.send("question#{my_random}") #display to user
if user_reply == self.send("answer#{my_random}")   #validate against user's reply
    p 'success'
else
    fail_count += 1
end
```

Comment: what does .send does? sends data to where? am i suppose t o try and place this code in my model or view or controller?

Comment: 'send'  converts a string into a method call on your instance. see http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Object.html#method-i-send for more details.

Comment: updated for a better example of how to use it, as for where to place this, you'll need to know what question to display when your form renders, so your login action in your controller needs to decide what question.  once the user submits you can then validate their answer with the one stored for that user

Comment: This is getting the random question as well as the answer but how to make it relevant to that particular user only?

Comment: maybe im not clear on your questio thenn,  above you noted the Model 'Members' has attributes that include questions and answers for a given user.  Is that not an ActiveRecord model?  What is the data structure 'Members' you provide above?